# ember + Could not find module `@ember/application`

Tags: javascript, ember.js, module

I have a ember app, after start server, log this error in console:

> Error: Could not find module `@ember/application` imported from `app`

Comment: Can you post your imports from app.js file? How did you init the app? Via ember-cli? What ember version are you using?

Comment: Please show your package.json, and clarify if you have a yarn.lock or package-lock.json. try to remove node_modules and run yarn or npm install.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on ember/ember-cli version > 2.16 and using yarn with latest node preferably nodejs: 8.8.1, npm: 5.5.1.

Also, go through the deprecations to understand how and why ember has been upgraded from previous versions --> https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x